# dispatch_Async serial queue

Tags: ios, queue, dispatch-async

I couldn't guess the output of it.

```
dispatch_async(serial_queue,^{NSlog(@"1");});

NSlog(@"2");

dispatch_async(serial_queue,^{NSlog(@"3");});

NSlog(@"4");
```

AFAIK

The output is

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4

But I am not sure !

Can anybody explain If I am wrong !

Comment: the output should be theoretically unpredictable, since there is no guarantee when the async blocks will execute... but i guess maybe those async blocks execute too quickly for the order to ever be different

Comment: There should be some response right ! because the question was thrown at me in a iOS written interview test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the interleaving of the operations may not be known, you can see that there are two streams.  The first is logging from a serial queue, the other is just plain NSLog.

What you can say about the order is that `1` will precede `3` and `2` will precede `4`